# Android powermanager / wakelock problem

Tags: android, screen

I have made a class:

```
package com.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;

public class DoNotDimScreen extends Activity {

private PowerManager.WakeLock wl;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "DoNotDimScreen");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();
wl.release();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
wl.acquire();
}
}
```

That i want to use in my main class to turn the screen on and off at certain hours of the day, so ve tried the following (in my main class):

```
DoNotDimScreen dm = new DoNotDimScreen();

 if (hourOfDay == 5) 
  dm.onResume();
    else
     dm.onPause();
```

But i get a nullpointerexception. What am i doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to read up on the `Activity` lifecycle.  You should never use the `new` keyword to instantiate an `Activity` directly, nor should you call `onResume` or `onPause`.  Here are some links for you to read:

- [Application Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html)
- [Activity documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ok Johan let me help you,

Pass the application context to your main activity. There you can create the instance of wakelock then. Acquire the wakelock wnerever you need and vice versa.

```
      if (hourOfDay == 5)    
        Wl.acquire();     
     else      
        wl.release();
```

Be sure you dont pass context null.

Cheers...!!

Answer (score -2):

You have to understand activity life cycle of the android.You can not called lifecycle method like that.
But if you want acquire()/release() within specific time period it can be done using following code.